# Ajax call to Servlet doesn't show Servlet response on the same page

Tags: ajax, eclipse, servlet-3.0

I have a Dynamic Web project Ajaxdemo which contains a JSP file testingAjax.jsp. I want to trigger the servlet AjaxDemoServ from testingAjax.jsp using Ajax call and set the response of the servlet back to the same JSP file. The code of testingAjax.jsp is attached herewith:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>SO question 4112686</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on("click", "#somebutton", function() { // When HTML DOM "click" event is invoked on element with ID "somebutton", execute the following function...
$.get("/AjaxDemoServ", function(responseText) {   // Execute Ajax GET request on URL of "someservlet" and execute the following function with Ajax response text...
$("#somediv").text(responseText);           // Locate HTML DOM element with ID "somediv" and set its text content with the response text.
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="somebutton">press here</button>
<div id="somediv">Hi! I am Queen.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The servlet  AjaxDemoServ is as follows:

```
package ajaxdemo;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

//@WebServlet(value = "/AjaxDemoServ", loadOnStartup=0)
public class AjaxDemoServ extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public AjaxDemoServ() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String text = "some text";

        System.out.println("Text is:" + text);

        response.setContentType("text/plain");  // Set content type of the response so that jQuery knows what it can expect.
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); // You want world domination, huh?
        response.getWriter().write(text);  
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

P. S : I even tried using annotations @WebServlet but no change occurred!

It is Mozilla Firefox browser where I am running the application. How to check JavaScript console in Mozilla Firefox? If known, plz let me know how to check the same on Google Chrome. And this is the log contents which appear in console of Eclipse IDE when the project is running:

```
Jun 01, 2016 1:12:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin;C:\app\USER\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin;C:\oracle\ora90\bin;C:\oracle\ora90\Apache\Perl\5.00503\bin\mswin32-x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\jre\1.1.8\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;D:\eclipse-jee-juno-SR1-win32(3)Final\eclipse;;.
Jun 01, 2016 1:12:49 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:JustNow' did not find a matching property.
Jun 01, 2016 1:12:49 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:AjaxDemo' did not find a matching property.
Jun 01, 2016 1:12:50 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 01, 2016 1:12:50 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 01, 2016 1:12:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 542 ms
Jun 01, 2016 1:12:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jun 01, 2016 1:12:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.12
Jun 01, 2016 1:12:50 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [265] milliseconds.
Jun 01, 2016 1:12:50 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\JustNow\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Jun 01, 2016 1:12:51 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\AjaxDemo\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Jun 01, 2016 1:12:51 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]

    Jun 01, 2016 1:12:51 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start

INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 01, 2016 1:12:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1364 ms
```

Comment: What happens *instead*? Have you checked the browser's JavaScript Console? The server's logs?

Comment: When I am running the JSP, on pressing the submit button...no change in div text occurs i.e. the same text 'Hi! I am Queen.' on the same JSP page is displayed. Not the text which is set in servlet. I don't know how to check the browser's JavaScript Console. Plz tell me the way so that I can check it. After Tomcat starts, no exception is caught from anywhere.....server's log only contains red texts(as it happens actually!). Shall I post the log contents?

Comment: @ nitind When I am running the JSP, on pressing the submit button...no change in div text occurs i.e. the same text 'Hi! I am Queen.' on the same JSP page is displayed. Not the text which is set in servlet. I don't know how to check the browser's JavaScript Console. Plz tell me the way so that I can check it. After Tomcat starts, no exception is caught from anywhere.....server's log only contains red texts(as it happens actually!). Shall I post the log contents? – QUEEN 1 hour ago

Comment: How you check the JavaScript Console and network requests differs according to the browser, so which browser is it? And you should definitely be looking through the logs and posting anything that refers to your web app.

Comment: @nitind I have updated my question with the server log contents on console. Plz refer to the updated question for further queries and do help if possible.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor 

Also, you don't need to put a copy of the servlet API in the project. Tomcat already contains it and provides it for your web app.